# I cannot display data from sql server 2005 express on an ASP.net website running from IIS windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, iis, connection-string

I am using Microsoft server 2003 running sql server 2005 which I have added an asp.net website on IIs.This works perfect. I can display the website on the browser and also read information from the sql server. My problem now arises when I want to do exactly the same but with my laptop which is running sql server 2005 express on windows 7. the websites displays just fine on the localhost but when I login it gives me an error saying that it cannot read files.
So my question is that is there a difference between sql server connectionstring and sql server express connection string? or the error is not connectionstring related?

Comment: the connection strings will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the connection string for SQL Server CE is typically different from SQL Server. SQL Server CE is "self hosted." You basically connect to a file in your `app_data` directory. SQL Server, in contrast, has many ways to connect to it: via TCP/IP, Named Pipes, etc.

A typical SQL Server connection string is this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

A typical SQL Server CE connection string is this:

```
Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Notice how for SQL Server CE you specify the path to your database file. For SQL Server, you typically specify the **server** running the SQL Server Service.

Many more examples [here.](http://connectionstrings.com/)